Factory functions for msal angular are executed before the APP_INITIALIZER
I am authenticating a user through Microsoft Azure AD in my Angular application(SPA) and I want to provide clientId dynamically in IPublicClientApplication. To achieve this I am calling backend endpoing which return client Id, which I store globally and trying to use in client_id field of auth object. But I am getting globalClientId as undefined but when I check in the initializeApp function globalClientId has expected value.
The issue seems to be that the MSAL (Azure AD) providers are executing before the APP_INITIALIZER function completes, which results in the clientId being unavailable at the time the MSAL configuration is initialized.
auth.service.ts
loadAppConfig(): Observable<any> {
        const payload = environment.appid;
        return this.http.post<any>(`${environment.apiUrl}/users/appData`, { payload }).pipe(
            tap(res => console.log('HTTP response:', res)) 
        );
    }


app.module.ts
let globalClientId = ''; 

export function initializeApp(authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {
  return () => authenticationService.loadAppConfig().toPromise().then(clientData => {
    globalClientId = clientData.config.clientId;
  }).catch(err => {
    console.error('Failed to load app configuration:', err);
  });
}

export function MSALInstanceFactory(): IPublicClientApplication {
  return new PublicClientApplication({
    auth: {
      clientId: globalClientId,
      authority: globalCloudInstance,
      redirectUri: globalRedirectUri,
      postLogoutRedirectUri: '/'
    },
    cache: {
      cacheLocation: BrowserCacheLocation.LocalStorage
    },
    system: {
      allowNativeBroker: false, 
      loggerOptions: {
        loggerCallback,
        logLevel: LogLevel.Info,
        piiLoggingEnabled: false
      }
    }
  });
}

// using MSALInstanceFactory in providers
providers: [
    { provide: MSAL_INSTANCE, useFactory: MSALInstanceFactory, deps : [AuthenticationService]}, 
]


I found the workaround with the help of following post and it has solved my issue, but I am searching for more appropriate solution
Angular (v15) providers for Azure AD are executed before the APP_INITIALIZER promise is resolved
(async () => {
  const data = await fetch('backend_url), {
    method: 'POST', 
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      someid : someid
    })
  });
  if (data.ok) { 
    const responseData = await data.json();     
    appData.clientId = responseData.auth.client_id;
  } else {
    console.error('Failed to fetch app data:', data.statusText);
  }

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).then(ref =>{
})
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
})();


please share the code of loadAppConfig and usage of MSALInstanceFactory code

@NarenMurali I have edited the code and added loadAppConfig and MSALInstanceFactory  usage
